# how to display a value of the variable in pine scritping?

Tags: pine-script

I need to check the current value of the variable in the PINE SCRIPTING. The purpose is to know the exact value of the variable of that time. I tried to search in the Reference Manual but I couldn't find it. I also tried to check YouTube but still couldn't get it. Please advise.

Plot function is not displaying the value of the variable. 
[screen shot of the code and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uagv.jpg)

Comment: You can use the plot() function for that.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am not getting the value. please check the below example                                                                                            signal_length = input(title="Signal Smoothing", type=input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
plot(signal_length) -- doesnt give the value

Comment: Please don’t add new information as a comment. Instead, edit your question and put it there. Could you also add a screenshot of your chart while you have this plot function?